# Access has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, express, cors

I have an Express server where I run the Angular app (because I need server side rendering).

The problem is that first time I make a request from the application everything works fine.

The problem appears when I navigate to some page, and come back to the previous page where the request worked fine. When I navigate back the request doesn't work anymore, it shows me the next error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myserver/api/endpoint' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I've tried to use CORS and other stuff, but it gives me the same error in the end.

This is the part where I use CORS:

```
const allowedOrigins = [
  'http://localhost:4000',
  'http://localhost:4200',
  'http://myserver'
];

const corsOptions = {
  origin: function(origin, callback) {
    if (!origin) {
      return callback(null, true);
    }

    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
      const msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not allow access from the specified Origin.';
      return callback(new Error(msg), false);
    }

    return callback(null, true);
  },
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS',
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type,Authorization'
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Have tried as well without CORS:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-Type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

So, what might be the problem that first time it works, and second time not?

Can this be related with this error from express console: 'ERROR TypeError: spanEl.getBoundingClientRect is not a function' ?

Comment: use `res.setHeader` instead of `res.header` in all lines also add `Authorization`

Comment: @JoelJoseph have tried, doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes to you code :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // website you wish to  allow to connet    
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

    // request method you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, OPTION, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // request headers you wish to allow 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');   

    // set to true if you need the website to include  cookies  in the  request  sent 
    // to the API (eg. in case you can see sessions )
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','false');

    // pass to the next layer of middleware
    next();

});
```